# ReactJs PropTypes Type Options

Tags: reactjs

In by Component below, I would like to require additional ReactPropTypes, but I am unsure of my options.

```js
var ContactItem = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    name: ReactPropTypes.string,
    number: ReactPropTypes.?????
  }
)}
```

What are the additional types that can be required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you a few basic ones:

```
React.PropTypes.bool
React.PropTypes.func
React.PropTypes.number
React.PropTypes.object
React.PropTypes.string
```

But I may advice you do go to the [React docs for reusable components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html), where you can find all the possibles values.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

And looking at the source code on github is event easier:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/types/ReactPropTypes.js#L69-L86